# What is a WQL query to get all devices connected to a specific hub?

Tags: windows, usb, powershell, wmi

What is the WMI / WQL Query syntax to get all devices connected to a specific USB Hub?

I can open up a PS terminal and enumerate all USB Hub Devices, as such:

```
 gwmi Win32_UsbHub | fl *
```

The output will return a list of all USB Hub device on the system. Here is a sampling of one such device.

```
Device ID: USB\VID_0451&PID_DD01\6&16FAF918&1&2, PNP Device ID: USB\VID_0451&PID_DD01\6&16FAF918&1&2, Description: Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
    Availability
    Caption=Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
    ClassCode
    ConfigManagerErrorCode=0
    ConfigManagerUserConfig=False
    CreationClassName=Win32_USBHub
    CurrentAlternateSettings
    CurrentConfigValue
    Description=Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
    DeviceID=USB\VID_0451&PID_DD01\6&16FAF918&1&2
    ErrorCleared
    ErrorDescription
    GangSwitched
    InstallDate
    LastErrorCode
    Name=Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
    NumberOfConfigs
    NumberOfPorts
    PNPDeviceID=USB\VID_0451&PID_DD01\6&16FAF918&1&2
    PowerManagementCapabilities
    PowerManagementSupported
    ProtocolCode
    Status=OK
    StatusInfo
    SubclassCode
    SystemCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
    SystemName=JMR-ENG-SARAH
    USBVersion
```

Using say the `PNPDeviceID` for this hub, I would like to get all connected devices, if any to it.

I am totally green with PS and WMI, but I thought of using `ASSOCIATES OF` as follows:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | select "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_UsbHub.DeviceID='USB\VID_0451&PID_DD01\6&16FAF918&1&2'}"
```

Annoyingly, enumerations do not list parent and children, though Device Manager does list things nicely and has a Parent.

[image: Device Manager view of a <code>Generic USB Hub</code> and <code>Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub</code> Showing Children]

Maybe just the way that I phrased things. Many other ways threw an error, so I did research and saw this syntax. I originally thought of using a `gwmi` command. In any event, I know from `Device Manager` that there are connected devices, but the above command yielded a blank screen.

`WMI Explorer` was not much help.

[image: WMI Explorer]

What would be the `SELECT` statement to use?

Answer (score 0):

Wow!... WMI Explorer, I've not seen that used in years. I still have it though, and others like it. PowerShellScript-o-Matic and the like 8^}

There are better ones instead of WMI Explorer, all written in PS.
Check out:

- http://blog.ctglobalservices.com/powershell/kaj/coretech-wmi-and-powershell-browser
- [https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PoweShell-ISE-Addon-CIM-5c9af37a](https://web.archive.org/web/20181227181639/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PoweShell-ISE-Addon-CIM-5c9af37a)

Anyway, as for you query. Not all things are possible with PS alone. There are lots of instances where you have to use real code, meaning, C#/C/C+/C++ to get this sort of stuff.

A lot of what you see in such MMC's of the OS are calls directly to some DLL/OCX file / programming reference, that is not directly exposed for PS to act on directly. This is why Add-Type exists, so, one can add C#/C/C+/C++, other language constructs to get or interop with what is needed.

All that being said… Is this, closer to what you are after?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_USBControllerDevice | 
%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |
Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |
Format-Table -AutoSize -GroupBy Manufacturer Description,Service,DeviceID

   Manufacturer: (Generic USB Audio)

Description      Service  DeviceID                                     
-----------      -------  --------                                     
USB Audio Device usbaudio USB\VID_047F&PID_C009&MI_00\8&461FC04&0&0000 
USB Audio Device usbaudio USB\VID_17A0&PID_0305&MI_00\9&109E1BB1&0&0000


   Manufacturer: (Standard keyboards)

Description         Service DeviceID                                     
-----------         ------- --------                                     
HID Keyboard Device kbdhid  HID\VID_045E&PID_00DB&MI_00\A&163A9F80&0&0000


   Manufacturer: (Standard monitor types)

Description         Service DeviceID                          
-----------         ------- --------                          
Generic PnP Monitor monitor DISPLAY\ACI2183\C&8538F4&0&UID256 
Generic PnP Monitor monitor DISPLAY\ACI27F6\8&5458763&0&UID256
Generic PnP Monitor monitor DISPLAY\ACI27F6\8&5458763&0&UID257
```

Or this...

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | 
Select Manufacturer,Description,Name,Service,DeviceID
```

Or see this...

> Device Management PowerShell Cmdlets
>
> This module exposes cmdlets that calls into SetupAPI functions and
> provides device enumeration and management functions.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388

---

##### Update per OP comment:

As per my comment to you. This should be useful for what you are after. You can read the whole article, it's short, but I've added the salient points here.

> UsbTreeView : View Usb devices and hubs they are in in a user friendly
> form
>
> http://flow-morewithless.blogspot.com/2014/05/usbtreeview-view-usb-devices-and-hubs.html
>
> you cannot get information about the connections because Microsoft
> wants that information to be hidden  Only way to get the
> child-parent-connection information would be to to go to driver level.
>
> A Visual C project compiled to an EXE.
>
> https://github.com/mkielar/get-parent-device
>
> Create a friendly name list (Powershell hash array) is in file
> UsbDeviceNames.ps1
>
> ```
> $OwnUsbDeviceNames = @{
> "USB\VID_04E5&PID_0605\6&13F4C3E&0&6"    = "Hama 4port passive USB hub ( the grey one)";
> "USB\VID_1A40&PID_0101\6&DF2EE03&0&5"    = "Deltaco Active Usb 2.0 cable";
> "USB\VID_1A40&PID_0101\7&19BC4090&0&1"    = "Delock USB2.0 4port active mini hub (the black round one)";
> "USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\FTFSDFHD"        = "FTDI Serial (COM5) to projector";
> "USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\FTFXXLHS"        = "FTDI Serial (COM8) to tv";
> "Something" = "is nothing"
> }
> ```
>
> The PS tool
>
> https://github.com/MarkoMarjamaa/UsbTreeView

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, however no. What I am after is that I specify the device ID of a specific USB hub, such as "Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub USBHUB3 
 USB\VID_0451&PID_DD01\6&16FAF918&1&2" and get back all the devices plugged into that hub. Yes, I realize that some external USB hubs have a "root" sub hub, which require going one-level deeper to gain access to all the devices plugged into the hub. Device Manager does a nice job, just I need to do the same in code.

Comment: The other scenario here is that the string you say you want to use are 4 different properties (Name, Caption) and the *ID (Device,PnP) strings contains several chars that are considered reserved / special in PS, thus char termination comes into play. DM does this by design of course, and like many things, MS is known for doing a good deal of stringifying stuff to make it more human readable, though the actual source is not like what is displayed. I done a bit more playing around, and thus far not looking promising.

Comment: Assuming a C# solution, then how would the solution look? Obviously, the solution is possible, as Device Manager shows the hub and the plugged in devices.

Comment: I am a true data hog, and when I find stuff interesting, I save it knowing it may come back to help or haunt me sooner or later. See my update for you. You'll note that the solution is two parts. A VC executable and then the PS stuff. It's not my code, just and item I have from circa 2014.